# C++/CLI unhandled exception passing 3 or more parameters to delegate

Tags: visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

Just stumbled upon strange behavior.

I have an unmanaged class (actually wrapper around some native lib):

```cpp
//.h
class Wrapper
{
private:
    void(*pCallback)(int, int /*, int*/);

public:
    void SetCallback(void(*callback)(int, int /*, int*/));
    void InvokeCallback();
};

//.cpp
void Wrapper::SetCallback(void(*callback)(int, int /*, int*/))
{
    pCallback = callback;
}

void Wrapper::InvokeCallback()
{        
    pCallback(0, 0 /*, 0*/); //(1)
    //(3)
}
```

And managed class which is winforms control and uses unmanaged wrapper described above:

```cpp
public ref class MineControl : public System::Windows::Forms::Control
{
private:
    Wrapper *pWrapper;
    delegate void CallbackDelegate(int, int /*, int*/);

public:
    MineControl()
    {
        /* rest of initialization here */

        pWrapper = new Wrapper;
        auto dlg = gcnew CallbackDelegate(this, &MineControl::Method);
        auto ptr = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(dlg);
        void(*callback)(int, int /*, int*/) = (void(*)(int, int /*, int*/))(ptr.ToPointer());
        pWrapper->SetCallback(callback);
        pWrapper->InvokeCallback();
    }

    void Method(int a, int b /*, int c*/)
    {
        //some code or even nothing at all
        //(2)
    }
}
```

This works fine.

Until I uncomment third parameter. After that I put breakpoint on `(1)`. I can enter to `MineControl::Mehod` - `(2)`. But everything fails on exiting this method. Point `(3)` become unreachable. I'm getting unhandled exception on exiting that method. Moreover being attached, VS still cannot handle that exception (all settings to debug unmanaged and managed code are set - this is the only case VS cannot catch exception). So Windows tries to handle it - standard `App has stopped working` window with two options - Debug and Close program. But I cannot debug because VS is still attached and either do not want to detach or app dies on VS detach.

I can wrap all parameters into some structure and this will work well. However can someone explain me why adding third parameter makes it impossible to get back from managed to unmanaged code?

I have no idea what is going on.

Environment: VS2013, x86 project, .net4.5

Comment: Your delegate is not a match for the callback, the stack gets imbalanced.  It requires [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)].  You are also not doing anything to ensure the delegate object stays referenced, a local variable is not good enough to convince the garbage collector.  Use a static variable or GCHandle::Alloc()

Comment: @HansPassant a warm thank you for pointing to calling convention  and note about `dlg` could be freed much early. I'm sure you saved lot's of hours of debugging for me :) Could you please repeat your comment as answer? It seems `stdcall` is default convention for C#, isn't it? Also why `GCHandle::Alloc()`? It need to be freed anyway. So I have to store it as my class's instance field. Why not store `dlg` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll post answer by myself. Solution is actually in [Hans's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414077/c-cli-unhandled-exception-passing-3-or-more-parameters-to-delegate#comment45163064_28414077).
Default calling convention is `sdtcall` but in my case I need `cdecl` calling convention.

Decorating delegate with `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]` attribute solved my problem.

There is also а valuable note that keep delegate in a local variable is a bad idea.